# jquery ajax "_method"="delete" gives a GET 404 when dataType:'script'

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I am doing a delete ajax request, like this-

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: delete_url,
    type:'post', 
    async: true,
    data: {"_method":"delete"},
    success: function(data) {
      alert("success");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("error:" + error.status);
    }
  });
```

It doesn't work on IE9, I don't see the delete request being sent to server in my logs. However, this is really weird because it works fine on Chrome. When I have "dataType:'script'", I get a 404 Not Found GET error both on Chrome and IE9. I have tried using type: "DELETE", unfortunately it doesn't work on IE9 but perfectly on Chrome/FF/Safari. I also tried adding _method=DELETE in the query string, but failed there too. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: question is confusing. What are you expecting to receive at server? and what data type are you returning from server? Is url on same domain?

Comment: on success, I want to remove a row that I have not included in the code above. dataType should be text/html but not script. Yes the url is on the same domain.

Comment: doesn't explain how you expect data formatted at server. ALso if returning html...what does `script` have to do with issue?

Comment: Found the solution- to get around this is IE9, I changed my route to delete via POST.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote:

> Found the solution- to get around this is IE9, I changed my route to delete via POST.

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments?rq=1).)